# Laravel 8: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project and I have built this form for verifying token:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <form action="{{ route('profile.2fa.phone') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="token" class="col-form-label">Token</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control @error('token') is-invalid @enderror" name="token" placeholder="enter your token">
            @error('token')
                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Validate token</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And then at `web.php` I have these routes:

```
Route::get('/settings/twofactor/phone' , [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'getPhoneVerify']);

Route::post('/settings/twofactor/phone' , [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'postPhoneVerify'])->name('profile.2fa.phone');
```

But now when I add the token and press the *Validate Token* button, I get this error:

> **Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException**
> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST.

So what is going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

---

Here are all routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('admin.index');
    });

    Route::resource('users' , App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminUserController::class)->middleware('admin');

    Route::get('/settings', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'index'])->name('profile');

    Route::post('/settings/twofactor' , [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'postManageTwoFactor'])->name('profile.2fa.manage');

    Route::get('/settings/twofactor/phone' , [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'getPhoneVerify']);
    Route::post('/settings/twofactor/phone' , [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'postPhoneVerify'])->name('profile.2fa.phone');

    Route::get('/auth/token' ,[App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthTokenController::class, 'getToken'])->name('2fa.token');
    Route::post('/auth/token' ,[App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthTokenController::class, 'postToken']);
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/auth/google', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\GoogleAuthController::class, 'redirect'])->name('auth.google');
Route::get('/auth/google/callback', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\GoogleAuthController::class, 'result']);

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Comment: It wouldn't be `{{ admin('admin.profile.2fa.phone') }}`?

Answer (score 2):

If you have routes like `/users/posts/`, `/users/posts/create`, and `/users/posts/edit` then create and edit routes should be written before `/users/posts` to avoid route conflict problem.

In your routes `web.php`, change the following routes order:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('admin.index');
    });

    Route::resource('users' , App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminUserController::class)->middleware('admin');

    Route::get('/settings/twofactor/phone' , [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'getPhoneVerify']);
    Route::post('/settings/twofactor/phone' , [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'postPhoneVerify'])->name('profile.2fa.phone');

    Route::post('/settings/twofactor' , [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'postManageTwoFactor'])->name('profile.2fa.manage');

    Route::get('/settings', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'index'])->name('profile');

    Route::get('/auth/token' ,[App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthTokenController::class, 'getToken'])->name('2fa.token');
    Route::post('/auth/token' ,[App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthTokenController::class, 'postToken']);
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/auth/google/callback', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\GoogleAuthController::class, 'result']);

Route::get('/auth/google', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\GoogleAuthController::class, 'redirect'])->name('auth.google');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still get the error!

Comment: Try running this: `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Error still appears: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. :(

Comment: Show me all the routes `php artisan route:list`

You can attach in the question

Comment: I just added all the routes to the question, plz check it out

Comment: I've updated the comment. There is an issue with the order of your routes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232481/discussion-between-tejoslaeslio-and-abdullah-shakir).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will solve if you try this one, just change the following line of your code with this one.

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Validate token</button>`

Answer (score 0):

button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">sent
This button solve your problem put this button in your form

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The error message "The GET method is not supported for this route" typically occurs when you try to access a route using the GET method, but the route definition only allows the POST method. In your case, the route /settings/twofactor/phone is defined to allow only the POST method, as shown in your code:

```
Route::post('/settings/twofactor/phone', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminSettingsController::class, 'postPhoneVerify'])->name('profile.2fa.phone');
```

However, in your form, you're using the POST method correctly:

```
<form action="{{ route('profile.2fa.phone') }}" method="POST">
```

To resolve the issue, you need to make sure that you're accessing the route with the correct HTTP method. Since your route only allows the POST method, you need to submit the form using the POST method.

If you're still encountering the error, there might be other factors causing the issue. Here are a few things you can check:

Clear your application's route cache by running the following command in your terminal:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Make sure there are no conflicting route definitions that could be causing the issue.

Ensure that there are no middleware restrictions or other route-related logic that may be interfering with the request.

By addressing these points, you should be able to resolve the "The GET method is not supported for this route" error.

Comment: Several of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76469738/python-pywinauto-how-to-control-custom-gui-gui-made-by-c-or-c-want-control/76469744#76469744